# Need help with simple algebra equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I would first like to impress that this is not a homework problem, but a personal one that I find myself unable to resolve, and that I am only an Algebra I student, and so I am unfamiliar with complex terminology. I need to solve the following equation for $X_2$ in the equation $D=\sqrt{(X_1-X_2)^2+(Y_1-MX_2)^2}$ calculating the difference of $X_1$ and $X_2$ on a coordinate plane when $M$ (the slope) and $D$, the distance between $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,MX_2)$. All assistance will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$D=\sqrt{(X_1-X_2)^2+(Y_1-MX_2)^2}$$

First squaring, and expanding:

$$\iff D^2 = (X_1-X_2)^2+(Y_1-MX_2)^2 = (X_1^2-2X_1X_2+X_2^2)+(Y_1^2-2MX_2Y_1+M^2X_2^2)$$

$$=(1+M^2)X_2^2-2(X_1+MY_1)X_2+(X_1^2+Y_1^2)$$

Now collecting all terms with $X_2^2$, with $X_2$ and those without the factor $X_2$:

$\iff (1+M^2)X_2^2-2(X_1+MY_1)X_2+(X_1^2+Y_1^2-D^2) = 0$$

Now this is a quadratic equation in $X_2$ which you can solve with the standard formula. I hope I got all the indices right.